# Flutter web configure server for single-app usePathUrlStrategy();

Tags: flutter, url, redirect, server, single-page-application

I have created a website with Flutter Web and uploaded it on an external web host (OVH). One of the functionalities of the site requires to access some pages via their URL (link with external service provider).

To show the page URL I use

```
usePathUrlStrategy();
```

When I uses the simulator (chrome), I can type URL in the address bar without any problem.
But when I build the app and upload the build on the server (OVH) the problem starts. When I try to manually access pages by typing the URL in the address bar, it returns an error 404 Page not found.

Flutter doc says:

> PathUrlStrategy uses the History API, which requires additional
> configuration for web servers.
>
> To configure your web server to support PathUrlStrategy, check your
> web server’s documentation to rewrite requests to index.html.Check
> your web server’s documentation for details on how to configure
> single-page apps.

Very well but I am unable to do it.
I tried with a *.htaccess* file redirecting every request to the *index.html* file (as I have read that the web app is a single file and that every request must be redirected towards that file) but it failed.

It is also important to mention that the external service provider will return to an URL of my site **with parameters** that I need to use in that page (with *Uri.base.queryParameters*)

May be useful to know, OVH servers run Apache.

Could you please help me?

Many thanks !